# threejs raycast to detect collisions, in FirstPerson

Tags: three.js

I am looking at various samples in threejs.

Issue
I want to use raycasting to make the camera stop at an object.

I have been able to use raycast to detect collisions.
However, it passes through the object.
Or if I walk backwards, it will pass through.

Sample code is below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-brahmagupta-j00rrw?file=/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using raycasting for detecting collision between the player's body and the environment is not recommended since it is very error prone. Even if you cast multiple rays in different directions from the player, the collision detection can still fail depending on how the player is oriented to a collider.

Instead of using raycasting, you normally want to use bounding volumes like bounding spheres, AABBs, capsules, OBBs or convex hulls and want to speed up tests spatial data structures like BVHs or Octrees. Check out the following official example that implements a basic FPS scenario with collisions:

https://threejs.org/examples/games_fps

Comment: thank you!Exactly what we were looking for.
I will try it as soon as possible.